# Doesn't show created mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing project using mongodb. so here I wrote separate functions to create db. this is my code

```
            $conn = new \MongoClient('mongodb://example.com:27017', array("connect" => TRUE));
            $exist_dbs = $conn->listDBs();

            foreach ($exist_dbs["databases"] as $databse) {
                if ($databse['name'] == $db_name) {
                    $is_exist = true;
                }
            }

            if (!$is_exist) {
                $db = new \MongoDB($conn, $db_name);
                $status = true;
                $msg = 'database successfully created';

            } else {
                $status = false;
                $msg = 'database already exist';
            }
            $conn->close();
```

but after create db it didn't show. but if I add record to that like this,

```
            $conn = new \MongoClient('mongodb://example.com:27017', array("connect" => TRUE));
            $exist_dbs = $conn->listDBs();

            foreach ($exist_dbs["databases"] as $databse) {
                if ($databse['name'] == $db_name) {
                    $is_exist = true;
                }
            }

            if (!$is_exist) {
                $db = new \MongoDB($conn, $db_name);
                $status = true;
                $msg = 'database successfully created';
                //new code
                $collection = new \MongoCollection($db, 'users');
                $obj = array("name" => "Madawa", "age" => "34");
                $collection->insert($obj);
            } else {
                $status = false;
                $msg = 'database already exist';
            }
            $conn->close();
```

it shows the database. what is the reason please help me.

Comment: The answer below by Crossphire Development is correct.

Comment: @acm ok thank you for your feedback, actually I wrote several functions separately to create db, drop db, add collections like wise. so think after create db I try to add collection to that db so how I avoid above problem(database not exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
$db = new \MongoDB($conn, $db_name);
```

You aren't creating a database, you are creating an object that can access a database.  It doesn't mean the database does exist or that it makes it, just that you now have an object capable of accessing it.  So you've basically said "Make me a database object to handle my calls and I'd like to select $db_name" but that is all that has happened.  The database doesn't exist until you put something into it or perform some action on it.

Comment: ok thank you for your feedback, actually I wrote several functions separately to create db, drop db, add collections like wise. so think after create db I try to add collection to that db so how I avoid above problem.